# Creating SpreadJS Editor Only Works With Alert

Tags: javascript, wijmo, eclipse-rap

I'm trying to create a RAP widget out of [this editor](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-enterprise/spreadjs/). The creating code looks like that:

```
    bindAll(this, [ "layout", "onReady", "onRender", "onSend" ]);
    this.parent = rap.getObject(properties.parent);

    this.htmlElement = document.createElement("div");
    this.htmlElement.id = "editor";
    this.htmlElement.style = "height: 100%;width: 100%";
    this.htmlElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    this.parent.append(this.htmlElement);
    this.parent.addListener("Resize", this.layout);

    alert('Creating editor...');

    $("#editor").wijspread({
        sheetCount : 1
    });

    rap.on("render", this.onRender);
```

Now that way the code works, but if I remove the "alert" the editor will not get created. I have very little knowledge of JS, but I found out that this is probably due to some asynchronous event taking place and not finishing in time before the `wijspread(...)` method is called. The question is: What event am I waiting for? And moreover: how can I wait for it to finish?

Comment: can you create a fiddle showing the issue as the code looks ok..

Comment: @Ashish I don't think that's possible; the same code works flawlessly in standalone HTML file. I guess without the AJAX all around the asynchronous event finishes early.